# Possible states of a 1-out-of-3

Tags: programming, probability-or-statistics, list-manipulation

I need to choose one or more cases of three, since $2^3=8$. How to make a program that is possible as shown in the table

[image]

My attempts

```
TableForm[Tuples[{p, q}, 3]]
```

$\begin{array}{ccc}
 p & p & p \\
 p & p & q \\
 p & q & p \\
 p & q & q \\
 q & p & p \\
 q & p & q \\
 q & q & p \\
 q & q & q \\
\end{array}$

But does not give a result as required in the table. Any Help

Comment: `Tuples[{{p1, q1}, {p2, q2}, {p3, q3}}]`?

Comment: @J.M. if $i=10$ , i.e., $p1, p2,...,p10 $  Do you type values like this for 10 times.

Comment: I might use `Table[]` + `Subscript[]` for that case; e.g. `Tuples[Transpose[{Array[p, 10], Array[q, 10]}]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
TableForm[
 Transpose[
  MapIndexed[
   {x, y} \[Function] Through[x[y[[1]]]], 
   Transpose[Tuples[{p, q}, 3]]
  ]
 ]
]
```

or

```
TableForm[
 Transpose[
  MapIndexed[
   {x, y} \[Function] Thread[Subscript[x, y[[1]]]],
   Transpose[Tuples[{p, q}, 3]]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

or

```
With[{a = 
   Transpose[
    MapIndexed[{x, y} \[Function] Thread[Subscript[x, y[[1]]]], 
     Transpose[Tuples[{p, q}, 3]]]]},
 TableForm@Join[a, Transpose[{Times @@@ a}], 2]
 ]
```

Comment: Is it possible to formulate them as in the table ... or to give a multiplication of cases with numbering

Answer (score 2):

Your notation and the complete enumeration of states suggests (to me) that maybe $q_i=1-p_i$.  If so, maybe this would work to calculate the probability of any particular history:

```
pr[history_] := Product[history[[i]] p[i] + (1 - history[[i]]) (1 - p[i]),
  {i, Length[history]}]

pr[{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}]
(* p[1] (1 - p[2]) p[3] p[4] (1 - p[5]) p[6] *)
```

If you wanted to leave $q_i$ as is, then

```
pr[history_] := Product[history[[i]] p[i] + (1 - history[[i]]) q[i], 
  {i, Length[history]}]

pr[{1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1}]
(* p[1] p[3] p[4] p[6] q[2] q[5] *)
```

To generate all possible combinations of a length of 4, you could use

```
pr[#] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1}, 4] // TableForm
```

[image: Table of probabilities]

Comment: Do not give any result at execution

Comment: What doesn't give a result at execution?  `pr[{1,0,1,1,0,1}]` does for me.